# If value not null then perform 'and' operation else skip the operation in 'which' linq condition

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

My Scenario is that I needed to search Employee Details based on either of the following 5 fields:

1. Employee Code  // If exist directly return result, based on ID
2. Employee Name
3. SelectedRankId
4. SelectedDistrictLocationId
5. SelectedOfficeLocationId

Here is a snippet of my code (which is not working)

```cs
// Model Validation -> Checking at least one value is passed, if Yes then,

IQueryable<EmployeeDetail> searchedData;
if (searchVM.EmpCode != null)
{
    searchedData = _db.EmployeeDetails.Where(x => x.EmpCode == searchVM.EmpCode);
}
else
{
    var normalizedName = searchVM.Name?.ToLower();

    searchedData = _db.EmployeeDetails
        .Where(x =>
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(normalizedName) ? x.EmpName.ToLower().Contains(normalizedName) : true
        && searchVM.SelectedRank != null ? x.CurrentRankId == searchVM.SelectedRank : true
        && searchVM.SelectedDistrictLocationId != null ? x.CurrentPlaceofPostingId == searchVM.SelectedDistrictLocationId : true
        && searchVM.SelectedOfficeLocationId != null ? x.CurrentlyPostedAtId == searchVM.SelectedOfficeLocationId : true);
}
```

Generated SQL by EF Core observer on Sql Server Profiler

```sql
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT [e].[EmpCode], [e].[Address], [e].[CreatedBy], [e].[CreatedOn], [e].[CurrentPlaceofPostingID], [e].[CurrentRankID], [e].[CurrentlyPostedAtID], [e].[DateOfBirth], [e].[EmpName], [e].[Gender], [e].[IsDeleted], [e].[JoiningDate], [e].[RetirementDate], [e].[Status], [e].[Telephone], [e].[UpdatedBy], [e].[UpdatedOn]
FROM [Employee_Details] AS [e]
WHERE (@__normalizedName_0 LIKE N'''') OR (CHARINDEX(@__normalizedName_0, LOWER([e].[EmpName])) > 0)',N'@__normalizedName_0 nvarchar(50)',@__normalizedName_0=N'test'
```

Even when I pass value for all of the Fields, still those are not getting considered while comparison. Below is my Http Request Data

```json
{
  "Name": "test",
  "EmpCode": null,
  "SelectedRank": 1,
  "SelectedDistrictLocationId": 4,
  "SelectedOfficeLocationId": 1,
  "Ranks": null,
  "DistrictLocations": null,
  "OfficeLocations": null
}
```

and I receive the following incorrect response (should have received only very 1st object):

```json
[
  {
    "EmpCode": 23,
    "EmpName": "Test User",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "DateOfBirth": "1999-01-30T00:00:00",
    "Telephone": "9873742414",
    "RetirementDate": "2041-10-23T00:00:00",
    "CurrentRankId": 1,
    "CurrentlyPostedAtId": 1,
    "CurrentPlaceofPostingId": 4,
    "JoiningDate": "2014-01-15T00:00:00",
    "Status": "Serving",
    "Address": null,
    "CreatedBy": null,
    "CreatedOn": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "UpdatedOn": null,
    "IsDeleted": null,
    "CurrentPlaceofPosting": {
      "Id": 4,
      "State": "state11",
      "Districts": "dist12",
      "EmployeeDetails": [
        null
      ],
      "PostedAtOffices": [],
      "PostingDetails": []
    },
    "CurrentRank": {
      "RankId": 1,
      "RankName": "BPO",
      "EmployeeDetails": [
        null,
        {
          "EmpCode": 121,
          "EmpName": "Test User",
          "Gender": "Female",
          "DateOfBirth": "2007-01-01T00:00:00",
          "Telephone": "9876543211",
          "RetirementDate": "2031-11-19T00:00:00",
          "CurrentRankId": 1,
          "CurrentlyPostedAtId": 1,
          "CurrentPlaceofPostingId": 1,
          "JoiningDate": "2009-01-01T00:00:00",
          "Status": "Serving",
          "Address": "asdfg,  asdas, asda21, 9129",
          "CreatedBy": null,
          "CreatedOn": null,
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedOn": null,
          "IsDeleted": null,
          "CurrentPlaceofPosting": {
            "Id": 1,
            "State": "Some 1",
            "Districts": "Dist 12",
            "EmployeeDetails": [
              null
            ],
            "PostedAtOffices": [],
            "PostingDetails": []
          },
          "CurrentRank": null,
          "CurrentlyPostedAt": {
            "Id": 1,
            "OfficeName": "Office 912",
            "OfficeLocationId": 26,
            "OfficeLocation": null,
            "EmployeeDetails": [
              null,
              null
            ],
            "PostingDetails": []
          },
          "PostingDetails": []
        }
      ],
      "PostingDetails": []
    },
    "CurrentlyPostedAt": {
      "Id": 1,
      "OfficeName": "office 121",
      "OfficeLocationId": 26,
      "OfficeLocation": null,
      "EmployeeDetails": [
        null,
        {
          "EmpCode": 121,
          "EmpName": "Test User",
          "Gender": "Female",
          "DateOfBirth": "2007-01-01T00:00:00",
          "Telephone": "9876543211",
          "RetirementDate": "2031-11-19T00:00:00",
          "CurrentRankId": 1,
          "CurrentlyPostedAtId": 1,
          "CurrentPlaceofPostingId": 1,
          "JoiningDate": "2009-01-01T00:00:00",
          "Status": "Serving",
          "Address": "asdfg,  asdas, asda21, 9129",
          "CreatedBy": null,
          "CreatedOn": null,
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedOn": null,
          "IsDeleted": null,
          "CurrentPlaceofPosting": {
            "Id": 1,
            "State": "Statuo 13",
            "Districts": "Dist146",
            "EmployeeDetails": [
              null
            ],
            "PostedAtOffices": [],
            "PostingDetails": []
          },
          "CurrentRank": {
            "RankId": 1,
            "RankName": "APO",
            "EmployeeDetails": [
              null,
              null
            ],
            "PostingDetails": []
          },
          "CurrentlyPostedAt": null,
          "PostingDetails": []
        }
      ],
      "PostingDetails": []
    },
    "PostingDetails": []
  },
  {
    "EmpCode": 121,
    "EmpName": "Test User",
    "Gender": "Female",
    "DateOfBirth": "2007-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Telephone": "9876543211",
    "RetirementDate": "2031-11-19T00:00:00",
    "CurrentRankId": 1,
    "CurrentlyPostedAtId": 1,
    "CurrentPlaceofPostingId": 1,
    "JoiningDate": "2009-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Status": "Serving",
    "Address": "asdfg,  asdas, asda21, 9129",
    "CreatedBy": null,
    "CreatedOn": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "UpdatedOn": null,
    "IsDeleted": null,
    "CurrentPlaceofPosting": {
      "Id": 1,
      "State": "State32",
      "Districts": "Ada dist",
      "EmployeeDetails": [
        null
      ],
      "PostedAtOffices": [],
      "PostingDetails": []
    },
    "CurrentRank": {
      "RankId": 1,
      "RankName": "DPO",
      "EmployeeDetails": [
        {
          "EmpCode": 23,
          "EmpName": "Test User",
          "Gender": "Male",
          "DateOfBirth": "1999-01-30T00:00:00",
          "Telephone": "9873742414",
          "RetirementDate": "2041-10-23T00:00:00",
          "CurrentRankId": 1,
          "CurrentlyPostedAtId": 1,
          "CurrentPlaceofPostingId": 4,
          "JoiningDate": "2014-01-15T00:00:00",
          "Status": "Serving",
          "Address": null,
          "CreatedBy": null,
          "CreatedOn": null,
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedOn": null,
          "IsDeleted": null,
          "CurrentPlaceofPosting": {
            "Id": 4,
            "State": "some place",
            "Districts": "some district",
            "EmployeeDetails": [
              null
            ],
            "PostedAtOffices": [],
            "PostingDetails": []
          },
          "CurrentRank": null,
          "CurrentlyPostedAt": {
            "Id": 1,
            "OfficeName": "some office 1121",
            "OfficeLocationId": 26,
            "OfficeLocation": null,
            "EmployeeDetails": [
              null,
              null
            ],
            "PostingDetails": []
          },
          "PostingDetails": []
        },
        null
      ],
      "PostingDetails": []
    },
    "CurrentlyPostedAt": {
      "Id": 1,
      "OfficeName": "Office 2",
      "OfficeLocationId": 26,
      "OfficeLocation": null,
      "EmployeeDetails": [
        {
          "EmpCode": 23,
          "EmpName": "Test User",
          "Gender": "Male",
          "DateOfBirth": "1999-01-30T00:00:00",
          "Telephone": "9873742414",
          "RetirementDate": "2041-10-23T00:00:00",
          "CurrentRankId": 1,
          "CurrentlyPostedAtId": 1,
          "CurrentPlaceofPostingId": 4,
          "JoiningDate": "2014-01-15T00:00:00",
          "Status": "Serving",
          "Address": null,
          "CreatedBy": null,
          "CreatedOn": null,
          "UpdatedBy": null,
          "UpdatedOn": null,
          "IsDeleted": null,
          "CurrentPlaceofPosting": {
            "Id": 4,
            "State": "Statu16",
            "Districts": "bt Dist",
            "EmployeeDetails": [
              null
            ],
            "PostedAtOffices": [],
            "PostingDetails": []
          },
          "CurrentRank": {
            "RankId": 1,
            "RankName": "CPO",
            "EmployeeDetails": [
              null,
              null
            ],
            "PostingDetails": []
          },
          "CurrentlyPostedAt": null,
          "PostingDetails": []
        },
        null
      ],
      "PostingDetails": []
    },
    "PostingDetails": []
  },
  {
    "EmpCode": 178490,
    "EmpName": "Test201",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "DateOfBirth": "2000-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Telephone": "9873742567",
    "RetirementDate": "2033-12-01T00:00:00",
    "CurrentRankId": 6,
    "CurrentlyPostedAtId": 3,
    "CurrentPlaceofPostingId": 3,
    "JoiningDate": "2023-03-01T00:00:00",
    "Status": "Serving",
    "Address": "kasdk",
    "CreatedBy": null,
    "CreatedOn": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "UpdatedOn": null,
    "IsDeleted": null,
    "CurrentPlaceofPosting": {
      "Id": 3,
      "State": "Goon State",
      "Districts": "Bad Dist",
      "EmployeeDetails": [
        null
      ],
      "PostedAtOffices": [],
      "PostingDetails": []
    },
    "CurrentRank": {
      "RankId": 6,
      "RankName": "Notice Server",
      "EmployeeDetails": [
        null
      ],
      "PostingDetails": []
    },
    "CurrentlyPostedAt": {
      "Id": 3,
      "OfficeName": "Office 23",
      "OfficeLocationId": 26,
      "OfficeLocation": null,
      "EmployeeDetails": [
        null
      ],
      "PostingDetails": []
    },
    "PostingDetails": []
  },
  {
    "EmpCode": 178498,
    "EmpName": "Test User 10",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "DateOfBirth": "1994-01-01T00:00:00",
    "Telephone": "9873742417",
    "RetirementDate": "2023-03-31T00:00:00",
    "CurrentRankId": 4,
    "CurrentlyPostedAtId": 5,
    "CurrentPlaceofPostingId": 5,
    "JoiningDate": "2022-12-01T00:00:00",
    "Status": "Serving",
    "Address": "asd, asdas, asdas",
    "CreatedBy": null,
    "CreatedOn": null,
    "UpdatedBy": null,
    "UpdatedOn": null,
    "IsDeleted": null,
    "CurrentPlaceofPosting": {
      "Id": 5,
      "State": "Hard State",
      "Districts": "Super Dist",
      "EmployeeDetails": [
        null
      ],
      "PostedAtOffices": [],
      "PostingDetails": []
    },
    "CurrentRank": {
      "RankId": 4,
      "RankName": "Senior Super Rank",
      "EmployeeDetails": [
        null
      ],
      "PostingDetails": []
    },
    "CurrentlyPostedAt": {
      "Id": 5,
      "OfficeName": "Dputysd sod",
      "OfficeLocationId": 26,
      "OfficeLocation": null,
      "EmployeeDetails": [
        null
      ],
      "PostingDetails": []
    },
    "PostingDetails": []
  }
]
```

Comment: You need to add parentheses around your conditional operators `?:`. See the Operator Precedence section of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/). Conditional AND `&&` has a higher precedence that the `?:` conditional, so `true && searchVM.SelectedRank != null` and other `&&` operations are being evaluated before `?:`. I expect that adding parentheses so you have `.Where(x => (p1 != null ? test-for-p1 : true) && (p2 != null ? test-for-p2 : true) && ...)` whould work.

Comment: I would usually code this as `searchedData = _db.EmployeeDetails;` followed by a series of `if (p1 != null) { searchedData = searchedData.Where(x => test-for-p1); }` and similar for the other optional filters. However, based on your posted SQL Server Profiler capture, it appears that EF Core might already recognize and evaluate client-side expressions, eliminating the unnecessary tests.

Comment: @TN , It was all Precedence Issue, Thank you soo much.
Add it as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add parentheses around your conditional operators `?:`.

See the Operator Precedence section of [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/). Conditional AND `&&` has a higher precedence that the `?:` conditional, so `true && searchVM.SelectedRank != null` and other `&&` operations are being evaluated before `?:`.

I expect that adding parentheses so you have the following should work.

```
.Where(x => 
    (p1 != null ? test-for-p1 : true)
    && (p2 != null ? test-for-p2 : true)
    && ...
    );
```

I would typically code this as:

```
searchedData = _db.EmployeeDetails;
if (p1 != null)
{
    searchedData = searchedData.Where(x => test-for-p1);
}
if (p2 != null)
{
    searchedData = searchedData.Where(x => test-for-p2);
}
...
```

This dynamically builds the conditionals, completely skipping the unspecified conditions. However, based on your posted SQL Server Profiler capture, it appears that EF Core might already recognize and evaluate client-side expressions, eliminating the unnecessary tests during translation to SQL.